# Android Gradle build and circular dependency

Tags: android, build, gradle, dependency-management, circular-dependency

I have an Android project in IntelliJ IDEA. It consists of two modules: app and library. App depends on library and library depends on app (Yes, it's not good, but I have what I have and can't change this). IDEA in project settings warn me about circular dependencies, but project builds correctly. Project structure looks like this:

```
project
|__app
|    |__src
|    |__build.gradle
|__libarary
|    |__src
|    |__build.gradle
|__build.gradle
|__settings.gradle
```

Now I'm trying to migrate to new Android build system based on Gradle and have a trouble here. In my `build.gradle` from `app` module I add dependency on `library`

```
compile project(":library")
```

Also I tryed to add dependency in `library` on `app` like

```
compile project(":app")
```

But gets error from build system, when gradle trys to assemble library module:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Module version project:app:unspecified depends on libraries but is not a library itself
```

What I can do with this without changing project structure

Comment: Try to build them... simultaneously!

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: @mariosangiorgio, unfortunately nope, I changed my project structure

Comment: You would need to factor out the code both your app and your library need to use, if at all possible

Answer (score 1):

This parameters have changed.

You should now refactor:

In the library project use:

**apply plugin: 'com.android.library'**

In the app project use:

**apply plugin: 'com.android.application'**

Answer (score 0):

In the library project use:

`apply plugin: 'android-library'`

In the app project use:

`apply plugin: 'android'`

Make sure you have the newest Android tools:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'`

Answer (score 0):

If you arrive here searching for the same error with Android 3.0 you should know the current workaround is:

downgrade to kotlinVersion = '1.1.2-2'

and disable incremental build in gradle.properties kotlin.incremental=false

The issue is planned for the next alpha https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38447344